# Invalid object name '#Results' SSIS when using sp in dataflow

Tags: stored-procedures, ssis

I have a stored procedure that runs fine in SQL Management Studio but I'm having problems running it in SSIS 2008 R2. If I run it as an `Execute SQL Task`, it runs fine without any errors but when I use it as an ADO NET Source in a Data Flow Task, I get an error messaging

> Invalid object name #Results (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:208)

However when I click Preview, I do get rows of data displayed.

I don't have access rights to modify the stored procedure so I'm not sure what is going on inside the stored procedure itself but as I have said previously, I can run the stored procedure in management studio and when used in an Execute SQL Task in SSIS.

Answer (score 2):

One of the steps in SSIS is validation of metadata - the contract says we should have an integer and then a character size 8. When the data flow database source components (ado or ole) attempt to get their metadata, it's basically boils down the first query that is found.

The approach here is the same hack we use with dynamic tables in stored procedures. Change the stored procedure, which you've specified you *cannot* do, to provide a hint to SSIS on the expected metadata.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Sample
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Any condition that will never evaluate to true
    IF NULL = NULL
    BEGIN
        -- SSIS will key off of this query even
        -- though it is impossible for this branch to ever execute
        -- So, define our metadata here
        SELECT 
            CAST(NULL AS int) AS MyFirstColumn
        ,   CAST(NULL as char(8)) AS SomeCodeColumn;
    END

    -- Assume complex queries here that banjax the metadata
    -- yet ultimately return the actual data
    SELECT TOP 1000 
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS int) AS MyFirstColumn
    ,   CAST(LEFT(AC.name, 8) AS char(8)) AS SomeCodeColumn 
    INTO 
        #RubeG
    FROM 
        sys.all_columns AS AC;

    SELECT
        RG.MyFirstColumn
    ,   RG.SomeCodeColumn
    FROM
        #RubeG AS RG;

END
```

For sources of SQL Server 2012+, you can try to specify the `WITH RESULT SETS` property to your EXECUTE call.

```
EXECUTE dbo.Sample
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        c1 bigint
    ,   c2 varchar(8)
    )
);
```

### Biml

Sample biml package definition.

1. download and install [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com)
2. Open/create Integration Services project type
3. Add new biml file
4. Paste following definition
5. Adjust connection string value in line 5 (for OLE) an 8 (for ADO.NET)
6. Ensure the stored procedure dbo.Sample exists
7. Remove `DFT Sample Result Set` if using a 2008 database

Code here

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <Connection
            Name="tempdb"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=.\dev2014;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            />
        <AdoNetConnection
            Name="CM_ADO"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30;Database=tempdb;"
            Provider="SQL"
        />

    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_31206473">

            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Sample">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="OLESRC dbo_Source">
                            <DirectInput>EXECUTE dbo.Sample</DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Sample RESULTS SET">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="OLESRC dbo_Source RS">
                            <DirectInput>
                                <![CDATA[EXECUTE dbo.Sample
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        c1 bigint
    ,   c2 varchar(8)
    )
);]]>
                            </DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>

                <Dataflow Name="DFT SampleADO">
                    <Transformations>
                        <AdoNetSource ConnectionName="CM_ADO" Name="ADOSRC dbo_Sample">
                            <DirectInput>EXECUTE dbo.Sample</DirectInput>
                        </AdoNetSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>

                <Dataflow Name="DFT SampleADO RESULTS SET">
                    <Transformations>
                        <AdoNetSource ConnectionName="CM_ADO" Name="ADOSRC dbo_Sample">
                            <DirectInput>
                                <![CDATA[EXECUTE dbo.Sample
WITH RESULT SETS
(
    (
        c1 bigint
    ,   c2 varchar(8)
    )
);]]>
                            </DirectInput>
                        </AdoNetSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>

            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>

</Biml>
```

Sample metadata for an OLE Source

[image: Sample metadata]

WITH RESULTS SET metadata for an OLE Source

[image: WITH RESULTS SET metadata]

The results are the same for ADO.NET providers, I simply didn't notice that nuance to the question when I built my screenshots. Updated Biml makes it trivial to add those in though.

Comment: Kudos for answering your own question!  You could have just left it empty.  This makes Stack Overflow a better place!